# Remove final '\n' from string variable

Tags: string, bash, newline

I'm trying to remove the final `'\n'` character from a string variable.

For example:

```
string
string
string
\n
```

should simply become:

```
string
string
string
```

A lot of the examples I have seen do this for a file but not a variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post your attempts, you might be really close to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) like this:

```
variable="${variable%$'\n'}"
```

Comment: to keep the same value you will need to put it in quotes

Comment: Quotes aren't required on the RHS of an assignment; word splitting and file generation aren't applied.

Answer (score 1):

In BASH you can do this to remove last newline:

```
eol=$'\n'
str="${s%$eol}"
```